# RewriteCond - file test with path is not successfull

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

- I have file "/forms/Fuser.pm" in the document root.
- In the browser I need put this URL: "http://server/user"
- Rewrite must run this file: "/cgi-bin/form.pl?form=Fuser.pm"

Htaccess contain:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/forms/F%{REQUEST_URI}.pm -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cgi-bin/form.pl?form=$1 [QSA,L]
```

LOG shows:

```
`... RewriteCond: input='/data/server/web//forms/F/user.pm' pattern='-f' =>`not-matched
```

*Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Fedora)*

Comment: Set LogLevel rewrite:trace8 and stop guessing.

Comment: **LOG shows:** "... RewriteCond: input='/data/server/web//forms/F/user.pm' pattern='-f' => not-matched

Answer (score 1, accepted):

REQUEST_URI contains slash !

You must first extract URI without slash from the %{REQUEST_URI} !
Then you can try file test.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/(.*)$
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}forms/F$1.pm -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/cgi-bin/form.pl?form=$1 [QSA,L]
```